# Bootstrap 3 - Carousel example not working in IE10

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to use the Bootstrap 3 [carousel example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

When loading in Internet Explorer 10 (10.0.9200.16688 specifically), the top of the carousel does not flush to the top of the page, it appears just below the navigation like so:

[image]

It works fine on Firefox and Chrome (screenshot - Chrome):
[image]

How can I get the top of the carousel to flush top of the browser in Internet Explorer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For IE precautionary measures, is compatibility mode is turned off? Furthermore, this is running in IE10 Standards or in Quirks mode?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Compatibility mode is turned off. Turning it on will fix the issue of aligning the carousel to the top of the page however it breaks something else (the carousel circular buttons appear vertical instead of horizontal).

Comment: Not familiar with Quirks mode, I believe it is on because there is "<!DOCTYPE html>"  at the top of the code.

Comment: I see now that I've loaded it on IE, it's actually on purposely been styled like that by the Bootstrap team, not sure why although there's probably a good reason behind it.

Comment: But to make it the same as Chrome & Firefox, override `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: none;` on `.carousel-inner`

Comment: Thanks Mackiee appreciate it.. that's interesting, how do you know it's been purposely styled? Maybe it's a bug (version 3 have only just been released and some of the images don't work on the example). It looks pretty horrible and doesn't look the same on the version 2.3.3 example.

Comment: It's a guess, but with a team of developers & financial backing with the size of Twitter (The people who made Bootstrap), I'm sure their Q&A or Front-End Developers decided to have it the way it is! But who knows :) Add a ticket on their Github if you think it may be =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` and override it to `overflow: none;` on `.carousel-inner` class that's wrapped within the `#myCarousel` carousel container.

See below:

[image]

To further what I said in comments, sometimes some CSS Errors in IE often is a result of incorrect `<!DOCTYPES>` that triggers [Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) or Developer Defined Standards within the Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks MackieeE for donating your time and effort to help me. I did try commenting out "overflow: hidden;" from ".carousel-inner"  from the main bootstrap file, and then in the inline CSS added "overflow: none;" for the same class, however this didn't change it at all.

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom You might have to clear your Cache, Press F12 -> Ctrl + D!  As I'm not able to replicate the same issue after commenting it out :/

Comment: Hey, it seems to work if I un-check it using IE10 Dev tools however it doesn't seem to work if I override it (even with !important)

Comment: Sorry commenting out works fine, but overriding doesn't work. I'll assume it's down to IE and mark the question as answered, and raise a separate question if I can't figure out how to override. Thanks alot!